# Why doesn't my Ruby script run when I've moved the code to functions?

Tags: ruby, windows, function

I've a simple script which basically reads a RSS script & pushes it to twitter.

The script works fine, except when I move it all to functions and call the functions, it doesn't execute. Why is this so?

Here's what works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'
require 'bitly'
require 'twitter'

def setup_bitly()
   puts "Bitly setup"
   bitly_username = "<user-name>"
   bitly_apikey = "R_<api-key>"
   Bitly.use_api_version_3
   bitly = Bitly.new(bitly_username, bitly_apikey)
end 


def setup_twitter()
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = "<key>"
    config.consumer_secret = "<secret>"
    config.oauth_token = "<token>"
    config.oauth_token_secret = "<secret>"
    twitter = Twitter::Client.new
  end
end


bitly = setup_bitly()
twitter = setup_twitter()
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby"

puts 'Fetching and parsing feed: ' + url.to_s
    rss = SimpleRSS.parse open(url)

    rss.items.reverse.each_with_index do |i,idx|
    u = bitly.shorten(i.link, :history => 1)
    twitter_status = "#{i.title}" 
    puts twitter_status
    twitter.update(twitter_status)

    sleep 10

end
```

Here's the output:

```
C:\Users\Sathya\Documents\code\read-feed>read-feed.rb
Fetching and parsing feed: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby
Dynamic lists in rails 3
Ruby add dynamic events using AASM
```

If I move the last block to a function, it doesn't execute.  By "doesn't execute", I mean, the Ruby interpreter runs & quits, no (error) messages, nothing. Why is this so?

This is the version which is causing problems:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'
require 'bitly'
require 'twitter'

def setup_bitly()
   puts "Bitly setup"
   bitly_username = "<username>"
   bitly_apikey = "<api_key>"
   Bitly.use_api_version_3
   bitly = Bitly.new(bitly_username, bitly_apikey)
end 


def setup_twitter()
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = "<key>"
    config.consumer_secret = "<secret>"
    config.oauth_token = "<token>"
    config.oauth_token_secret = "<secret>"
    twitter = Twitter::Client.new
  end
end

def do_work()
  url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby"
  puts 'Fetching and parsing feed: ' + url.to_s
  rss = SimpleRSS.parse open(url)
  rss.items.reverse.each_with_index do |i,idx|
    u = bitly.shorten(i.link, :history => 1)
    twitter_status = "#{i.title}"
    puts twitter_status
    twitter.update(twitter_status)
    sleep 10
end

bitly = setup_bitly()
twitter = setup_twitter()
do_work()

end
```

If I run this, the script runs & quits:

```
C:\Users\Sathya\Documents\code\read-feed>read-feed.rb
```

I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit on  Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal, your function doesn't see the variables `bitly` and `twitter`.

You can do one the following:

- Pass them as arguments to your function.
- Wrap the function in a class and use @instance variables.
- Use global variables (please do not :) )

Comment: Err.. yeah I look stupid now, don't I? Thanks for pointing out the obvious mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this runs quietly without errors? There are at least 2 problems with the code as is:

1. You are calling `twitter.update` in `do_work` without having a local variable called `twitter` in scope. Same goes for `bitly`.
2. There's an extra `end` in the last line.

Comment: There should have been an extra `end` but @yi_h points out the most glaring error about variables not being in scope. And yes, the script does run!

Comment: What would that extra `end` be for? This is what happens if I just copy/paste your code: `→ ruby -c foo.rb
foo.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end`

Comment: That "extra end" is the reason you're not even seeing any errors.  It does pair, but it pairs with the `def do_work` and therefore you have no code outside of your methods that is actually being invoked.  This is mostly because you have indented your code correctly, so it's difficult to see.

Comment: @d11wtq: Good spot, I didn't read closely enough, I just saw an `end` aligned with the `def` and then another one later one.